# create dropdown list in excel that displays different values from the same lookup table

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown, vlookup

I am trying to create a dropdown list in excel that once chosen, the text will display a different value in reference to a table on another sheet. In my example I want to have a more common site name be displayed in the dropdown, but then have the StationID be displayed once chosen. I've tried the follow VB code that I found but cannot seem to get it to work for my example. Again, these are in the same workbook but in separate worksheets is all I can think of causing an issue. I changed the code by trying to create a variable for the lookup table on the separate worksheet, but it still doesn't work. Here is the code block I found and it didn't work for my example.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Created By Excel 10 Tutorial
    siteName = Target.Value
    defRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“LookUpTable”).Range(“WISKILookupTable”)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        StationNum = Application.VLookup(siteName, defRange, 2, False)
        If Not IsError(StationNum) Then
            Target.Value = StationNum
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uc8c.png)

Note, I already used data validation to create my original dropdown.

Comment: (1) fix those "smart quotes" to regular quotes (2) disable events before updating `Target` or you'll re-trigger the event (don't forget to re-enable events after that).  (3) `Set defRange = ` as noted by Richard.   If those don't fix it, then please expand on "doesn't work" - what happens when you select a value from the drop-down?  Maybe also (4) add in `If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub` so your code doesn't break when >1 cell is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Worksheet_Change() sub needs two edits:

```
Dim defRange As Range   ' Without this statement, defRange is a variant type, not a range
```

And add a `Set` statement to `defRange =`:

```
Set defRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“LookUpTable”).Range(“WISKILookupTable”)
```

That makes the `defRange` variable refer to the range itself. Otherwise `defRange` takes on the values in that range, which is not what you want.

Also, it's usually good practice to add an `Option Explicit` statement as the first line in the module. That will tell Excel to flag issues with variable types, and will catch the missing `Set` statement.

Of course, `Option Explicit` will force you to `Dim` every variable, but that's also good practice.